# Is the coding style following good practice

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

I have a utility class where I have saved the objects and other and the java classes calls this object. All the variables and methods are static here. I want to know whether it is a good practice or not. And are there any security threats to my application or not.

```
public class ObjectHolderUtil {
/**
* Object of the main stage of the application
*/
public static Stage mainStage;
public static HibernateSession hibernateSession;
public static String dashboard="/fxml/Dashboard.fxml"; //dashboard fxml file
public static String mainScreen="/fxml/MainScreen.fxml";
public static String addBill="/fxml/AddBill.fxml";
public static StackPane mainStackPane;
public static User user;

public static Helper helper;

  public static String getMainScreen() {
    return mainScreen;
  }

  public static void setMainScreen(String mainScreen) {
    ObjectHolderUtil.mainScreen = mainScreen;
  }

  public static Helper getHelper() {
    return helper;
  }

  public static void setHelper(Helper helper) {
    ObjectHolderUtil.helper = helper;
  }

  public static User getUser() {
    return user;
  }

  public static void setUser(User user) {
    ObjectHolderUtil.user = user;
  }

 public static StackPane getMainStackPane() {
    return mainStackPane;
  }

  public static void setMainStackPane(StackPane mainStackPane) {
    ObjectHolderUtil.mainStackPane = mainStackPane;

  }

  public static Stage getMainStage() {
    return mainStage;
  }

  public static void setMainStage(Stage mainStage) {
    ObjectHolderUtil.mainStage = mainStage;
  }

  public static String getDashboard() {
    return dashboard;
  }

  public static void setDashboard(String dashboard) {
    ObjectHolderUtil.dashboard = dashboard;
  }

  public static HibernateSession getHibernateSession() {
    return hibernateSession;
  }

  public static void setHibernateSession(HibernateSession hibernateSession) {
    ObjectHolderUtil.hibernateSession = hibernateSession;
  }
}
```

And I would call the object of this class as 
`ObjectHolderUtil.setMainStackPane(mainStackPane);`

Comment: Consider using a singleton, or a normal class with a single instantiation instead?

Comment: There is no need to everything to be static. Maybe the class should be a Singleton instead. Also do not expose your class variables as public. They should be private.

Comment: @Bathsheba - If this is just a utility class, then making the constructor private would be enough right?

Comment: This question may be more appropriate on CodeReview.

Comment: If it's analogous to a C++ namespace of utility-like functions that don't require a `this` pointer, then the closest analogue I can think of in Java is a purely static final class with no fields and a private constructor. But the OP has static fields, so this is different.

Comment: @Bathsheba a class cannot be static in Java(unless it's a inner class), i think there is no need to create a singleton class, just marking fields as private, declaring a private no-arg constructor and declaring class as final would suffice?

Comment: @Bathsheba - Hmm. I don't quite understand why the OP has a helper class inside a util class. Maiking it a UtilHelper

Comment: @VinodMadyalkar we can't say anything since we don't know what's written in that helper class :)

Comment: @SarthakMittal - I was merely pointing to the naming convention. Util classes are themselves helper classes.

Comment: @VinodMadyalkar yeah i agree, naming a class as "Helper" is way too abstract.

Comment: I have updated my question. Please suggest me how to code this by not making static variables and methods

Comment: Having all methods static and having/being a Singleton are two completely different things and serve completely different purposes! However I agree that there is no need for "static" just make a normal class from that with a no arg ctor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to avoid any static things if possible. In OO we tend to use Objects for everything and doing static things only if absoluty nessecary or by having a good reason.

A util class is used if you have some methods to solve simple tasks which do not belong in any class (rarely the case). Not what you want.

I removed some of your varriables and methods to make the code shoter...

**Varriante 1 - Constructor**

You could create this object multiple times and have multiple instances of it. But you could also create just one - which is nice.
Kind of like you can open the windows explorer multiple times

*Information holder*

```
public class BillingServrice {

  private Stage mainStage;
  private StackPane mainStackPane;
  private User user;
  private HibernateSession hibernateSession;

  public BillingServrice() {
    // create all the other objects here
    // pass this as parameter
    mainStage = new Stage(this);
    mainStackPane= new StackPane (this);
  }

  // ... all the getters and setters
}
```

*The object*

```
public class Stage {

  private BillingServrice billingServrice;

  public Stage (BillingServrice billingServrice) {
    this.billingServrice = billingServrice;

  }

  void doSomething() {
     System.out.println( billingServrice.getUser() );
  }

}
```

**Varriante 2 - Singleton**

There will be only one of this, there is no way to create this one multiple times. This could cause a problme in some cases, if you do not completly understand this pattern.

*Information holder*

```
public class BillingServrice {

  private static BillingServrice billingServrice;

  public static BillingServrice getInstance() {

    if(billingServrice == null) billingServrice = new BillingServrice();
    return billingServrice;

  }

  private Stage mainStage;
  private StackPane mainStackPane;
  private User user;
  private HibernateSession hibernateSession;

  private BillingServrice() {
    // You need to define the constuctor
  }


  // ... all the getters and setters


}
```

*The object*

```
public class Stage {

  private BillingServrice billingServrice;

  public Stage () {
    this.billingServrice = BillingServrice.getInstance();

  }

  void doSomething() {
     System.out.println( billingServrice.getUser() );
  }

}
```

Comment: I have updated my question. Please suggest me how to code this by not making static variables and methods. This single class is accessed by multiple classes at multiple times

For example: 
MainStageController.java could use getMainScreen(); at one place and 
setUser(); at other place

LoginController.java could use getUser(); at one place and setMainStackPane at other place

Comment: Okay now what I have done is I have removed the `static` word and mafe it a normal class. Now when I want to access this class, I simply extend it and access its methods. But the problem now is child class A accesses one object of this Parent class and child class B accesses another object of the Parent Class. I want one object of the Parent class to be accessed by all the child classes. How would I do that

Comment: No, that's not good either. Inheriting should really be used if the child is somewhat the same as the partent - not in your case. I'll edit my answer again, to show how you would access it

Comment: Thank you. My problem is solved. This is the best answer that someone in stack overflow community has given to me. You were really there to solve my problem.